# How can I manipulate/format string, in Ansible, based on loop index?

Tags: ansible

I need to output these strings in my Ansible role.

```ini
jdbc_connection_string_np=jdbc:mysql://dbint1:3306/np
jdbc_connection_string_np2=jdbc:mysql://dbint2:3306/np
```

It is easy to output:

```ini
jdbc_connection_string_np0=jdbc:mysql://dbint1:3306/np
jdbc_connection_string_np1=jdbc:mysql://dbint2:3306/np
```

by doing this

```yaml
- name: Debug JDBC lines
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "jdbc_connection_string_np{{ my_idx }}=jdbc:mysql://{{ item }}:3306/np"
  with_items: "{{ groups['db'] }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: my_idx
```

But the string `np0` needs to be `np` and `np1` should be `np2`.
I tried this:

```yaml
msg: "jdbc_connection_string_np{{ my_idx + 1 | string | regex_replace('1', '') }}=jdbc:mysql://{{ item }}:3306/np"
```

But I get the error message:

```
Unexpected templating type error occurred on ... unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: If you feel like your solution deserves a self answer, please do so. But don't edit with a solution inside the question thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Case**

> *I need to output these strings in my Ansible role.
> `jdbc_connection_string_np=jdbc:mysql://dbint1:3306/np jdbc_connection_string_np2=jdbc:mysql://dbint2:3306/np`*

**Solution**

The minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Example loop

    debug:
      msg: "jdbc_connection_string_np{{ item | regex_replace('1', '') }}=jdbc:mysql://dbint{{ item }}:3306/np"

    loop: "{{ range(1,3) }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Example loop] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: jdbc_connection_string_np=jdbc:mysql://dbint1:3306/np
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: jdbc_connection_string_np2=jdbc:mysql://dbint2:3306/np
```

You may also have a look into [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) and

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Example loop

    debug:
      msg: "jdbc_connection_string_np{{ ansible_loop.index | regex_replace('1', '') }}=jdbc:mysql://{{ item }}:3306/np"

    loop: ['dbint1', 'dbint2']
    loop_control:
      extended: true
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Example loop] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=dbint1) =>
  msg: jdbc_connection_string_np=jdbc:mysql://dbint1:3306/np
ok: [localhost] => (item=dbint2) =>
  msg: jdbc_connection_string_np2=jdbc:mysql://dbint2:3306/np
```

---

**Error Message**

```
Unexpected templating type error occurred on ... unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Regarding the type casting and format mismatch of your string and arithmetic operation

```yaml
{{ my_idx + 1 | string | regex_replace('1', '') }}
```

I've found the following working

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Example loop

    debug:
      msg: "{{ '%01d' | format(my_idx + 1) }}"
    loop: ['dbint1', 'dbint2']
    loop_control:
      index_var: my_idx
```

and resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Example loop] ************
ok: [localhost] => (item=dbint1) =>
  msg: '1'
ok: [localhost] => (item=dbint2) =>
  msg: '2'
```

**See Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to joint string and integer to become new string?](https://serverfault.com/a/1068032/448950)

Answer (score 2):

Given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
[db]
dbint[1:2]
```

---

1. Use the filter *ternary* to create the index

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "jdbc_connection_string_np{{ idx }}=jdbc:mysql://{{ item }}:3306/np"
      loop: "{{ groups.db }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx
      vars:
        idx: "{{ (my_idx > 0)|ternary(my_idx + 1, '') }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [dbint1] => (item=dbint1) => 
  msg: jdbc_connection_string_np=jdbc:mysql://dbint1:3306/np
ok: [dbint1] => (item=dbint2) => 
  msg: jdbc_connection_string_np2=jdbc:mysql://dbint2:3306/np
```

---

2. Instead of the iteration, you can get the index from the hostname. Declare the variables in *vars*. You can iterate the connection strings either in Jinja or in Ansible if you want to

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_idx: "{{ inventory_hostname[5:] }}"
    idx: "{{ (my_idx|int > 1)|ternary(my_idx, '') }}"
    conn: "jdbc_connection_string_np{{ idx }}=jdbc:mysql://{{ inventory_hostname }}:3306/np"

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        conn: "{{ conn }}"
    - debug:
        var: conn

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for host in groups.db %}
          {{ hostvars[host].conn }}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[item].conn }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.db }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [dbint1] => 
  conn: jdbc_connection_string_np=jdbc:mysql://dbint1:3306/np
ok: [dbint2] => 
  conn: jdbc_connection_string_np2=jdbc:mysql://dbint2:3306/np

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [dbint1] => 
  msg: |-
    jdbc_connection_string_np=jdbc:mysql://dbint1:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np2=jdbc:mysql://dbint2:3306/np

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [dbint1] => (item=dbint1) => 
  msg: jdbc_connection_string_np=jdbc:mysql://dbint1:3306/np
ok: [dbint1] => (item=dbint2) => 
  msg: jdbc_connection_string_np2=jdbc:mysql://dbint2:3306/np
```

---

3. If you want to use *regex_replace* instead of *ternary* you must match '1' exactly at the beginning of a single-digit string. For example, by the Python regex lookahead assertion *`^(?=\d)`*. The play below gives the same results

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_idx: "{{ inventory_hostname[5:] }}"
    idx: "{{ my_idx|regex_replace('^(?=\\d)1$', '') }}"
    conn: "jdbc_connection_string_np{{ idx }}=jdbc:mysql://{{ inventory_hostname }}:3306/np"

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        conn: "{{ conn }}"

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for host in groups.db %}
          {{ hostvars[host].conn }}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true
```

If you match the digit only '1'

```yaml
    idx: "{{ my_idx|regex_replace('1', '') }}"
```

the first 10 values of *idx* will repeat. For example, given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
[db]
dbint[1:12]
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    jdbc_connection_string_np=jdbc:mysql://dbint1:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np2=jdbc:mysql://dbint2:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np3=jdbc:mysql://dbint3:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np4=jdbc:mysql://dbint4:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np5=jdbc:mysql://dbint5:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np6=jdbc:mysql://dbint6:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np7=jdbc:mysql://dbint7:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np8=jdbc:mysql://dbint8:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np9=jdbc:mysql://dbint9:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np0=jdbc:mysql://dbint10:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np=jdbc:mysql://dbint11:3306/np
    jdbc_connection_string_np2=jdbc:mysql://dbint12:3306/np
```

---

Notes

- There are many options on how to get the index without iteration. For example, the method *index* gives the same results

```yaml
  my_idx: "{{ groups.db.index(inventory_hostname) + 1 }}"
```

- The next option is *regex_replace*

```yaml
  my_idx: "{{ inventory_hostname|regex_replace('^.*(\\d+)$', '\\1') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my own answer. I ended up doing this:

```
msg: "jdbc_connection_string_np{{ '' if my_idx == 0 else (my_idx | int) + 1 }}=jdbc:mysql://{{ item }}:3306/np"
```

and I kinda like it because it is Pythonic-ish. ;)